# In Razor, how to check existence of an object in ViewBag IEnumerable object based on a property of the element?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have model object called `AppPrivilege`, and it contains a public string property called `PrivilegeName`. In a controller, I generate a collection of those objects, and put them in the ViewBag, as follows (the other object types are all custom to my project):

```
SQLRolerecord toCheckPrivs = new SQLRolerecord();
IEnumerable<AppPrivilege> privsOfUser = toCheckPrivs.getPrivsForRole(roleUser);         
ViewBag.PrivilegeSet = privsOfUser;
return View();
```

Now in a view, how can I check whether there exists any element `AppPrivilege` that has a `PrivilegeName` of my choosing, such as "Read" for example? Here is the structure I am trying to achieve in the view:

```
  @if (ViewBag.PrivilegeSet != null)
        {
            if(ViewBag.PrivilegeSet.Contains(/*search criteria for PrivilegeName*/))
            {
                //valid code here

            }
        }
```

My approach to address this requirement consisted of generating a potentially large string of all the `PrivilegeName` values concatenated, and passing that through the ViewBag, upon which I could do string checking in the view. However, this seems not performance friendly, so I want to do it in a more proper way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ViewBag is a dynamic dictionary. You need to cast it to the specific type, `IEnumerable<AppPrivilege>` so that you can run LINQ extension methods on that.

Here is the code which use the `Any()` method to see at leaset one item exist in the ViewBag.PrivilegeSet collection with the `PrivilegeName` "Read"

```
@if (ViewBag.PrivilegeSet != null)
{
   var items = ViewBag.PrivilegeSet as IEnumerable<AppPrivilege>;
   if(items.Any(d=>d.PrivilegeName=="Read"))
   {
     <h1>Exist!</h1>
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Is there any drawback to using `==` instead of a string method?

Comment: In this string to string comparison, i prefer `=` for readability. Hereis a good post about it https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals/